# $.parseJSON returns correct items plus infinite undefined response

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm currently developing a flask application that retrieves the teams from a football league. The `teams_list` method returns the following response from an ajax request. I'm getting the right output but it's leading me into an infinite loop that really slows down the entire web application.

How I got the response:

```
teams = []
@app.route('/get_team_list', methods=['POST'])
    def team_list():
        league = request.form['team_name']
        id = get_league_id(league)
        get_teams(id)

        json_str = json.dumps({'status':'OK','id': id, 'league': league, 'teams': teams})
        json_obj = json.loads(json_str)

        temp = json_obj['teams'] #a subarray
        team_str = json.dumps(temp)
        print("STR:  ",team_str)
        print("JSON: ", str(temp))

        clear_team_array(teams)
        return team_str
```

Response:

```
["Juventus Turin", "Cagliari Calcio", "Hellas Verona FC", "SSC Napoli", "Atalanta BC", "AS Roma", "Udinese Calcio", "AC Chievo Verona", "US Sassuolo Calcio", "Genoa CFC", "UC Sampdoria", "Benevento Calcio", "SS Lazio", "SPAL Ferrara", "FC Internazionale Milano", "ACF Fiorentina", "Bologna FC", "Torino FC", "FC Crotone", "AC Milan"]
```

Ajax call:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: '/get_team_list',
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(response) {
           var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                for (var i = 0; json.length - 1; i++) {
                    console.log("RESPONSE: " + json[i]);
                }
       },
       error: function(error) {
           console.log("ERROR: "+ error)
       }
   });
});
```

It is working fine but the problem I'm heaving is that when I retrieve the teams through the `for loop` it gives me the following output:

```
RESPONSE: Juventus Turin
RESPONSE: SSC Napoli
RESPONSE: Atalanta BC
RESPONSE: AC Milan
RESPONSE: ...
(140231)REPONSE: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop conditional is `json.length - 1` which never changes so the loop keeps going forever.

It should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
```

Comment: It still giving me the same output. Plus, I wonder if the response from my function returns a valid JSON string? Right?

Comment: I got it! I changed `for (var i = 0; i < json.lenght - 1; i++) {..}` to `for (data in json) { consolse.log(json[data]); }` thanks anyway! I figured it out because of this.